# Why do these two ways of doing an embedding lookup give a different answer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Suppose I have the following matrix:

[image]

So, if I want to lookup the second row, I should get [3 4].

This is how I implemented the lookup mechanism using tensorflow operations:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.python.estimator.model_fn import EstimatorSpec


def model_fn_1(features, labels, mode):
    x = tf.constant([[1]])
    labels = tf.constant([[10.]])

    with tf.name_scope('Embedding_Layer'):
        m = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]], np.float32)

    lookup = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(m, x, name='embedding_matrix_1')
    lookup = tf.Print(lookup, [lookup])

    preds = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(lookup)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(labels - preds)
    train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss, tf.train.get_global_step())

    eval_metric_ops = {'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, preds)}
    return EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)


model_1 = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn_1)
model_1.train(input_fn=lambda: None, steps=1)
```

As expected, the output from `lookup` while training is:

```
2017-11-08 21:17:49.010728: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\kernels\logging_ops.cc:79] [[[3 4]]]
```

The problem is I do not get the same output when i try to implement the embedding lookup using Keras layers:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.estimator.model_fn import EstimatorSpec


def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    x = tf.constant([[1]])
    labels = tf.constant([[10.]])

    m = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]], np.float32)
    with tf.name_scope('Embedding_Layer'):
        n = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(2, 2, weights=[m], input_length=1, name='embedding_matrix_1', trainable=False)

    lookup = n(x)
    lookup = tf.Print(lookup, [lookup])

    preds = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(lookup)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(labels - preds)
    train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss, tf.train.get_global_step())

    eval_metric_ops = {'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, preds)}
    return EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)


model = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn)
model.train(input_fn=lambda: None, steps=1)
```

The output of `lookup` is some random numbers like:

```
2017-11-08 21:20:59.046951: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\kernels\logging_ops.cc:79] [[[0.532017469 0.885832787]]]
```

In my mind, the Keras implementation is identical to the tensforlow implementation. Why am I not getting the same output and how do I fix the Keras implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Currently `weights` is deprecated, you could use `embeddings_initializer` instead:

```
        n = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(2, 2, 
            embeddings_initializer=tf.initializers.constant(m), input_length=1, 
            name='embedding_matrix_1', trainable=False)
```

Then `keras`'s `Embedding(...)(x)` works exactly the same as `tensorflow`'s `tf.nn.embedding_lookup(emb_variable, x)`.

Answer (score -1):

Is there anything in common between these two implementations? `embedding_lookup` is just a lookup, it just extract information from `m` based on index `x`. But `keras.layers.Embedding` is a computation. Just check official documentation: https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/

Comment: In my Keras implementation, I let `n` be the matrix `m` using the `weights` parameter in Embedding. Then, when I call `n(x)` that should return the second row of `n` since `x` is 1. So, I think this should be the same as the call to `embedding_lookup` in the Tensorflow implementation. Besides, this way of implementing a lookup is suggested in the Keras blog as well: https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html.